# Split tables in one excel sheet to multiple other sheets based on continuity of data

Tags: excel

I am trying to automatically split multiple tables in one excel sheet to different sheets, based on the continuity of the data. Once there is a gap, like an empty row, it then starts a new sheet for the next table, and it is to be done multiple times as I have a lot of data in one sheet.

[image]

This is an image of a snippet of the data, the continuity of the data is not fixed, i.e. sometimes it is 4 rows, sometimes 20 etc. I want it to take the whole row of input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to extract all data to different worksheet

```
Sub spreaddate()

Dim totalrows As Integer
Dim countworksheet As Integer
Dim lastcopy As Integer
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Set Sht = ActiveSheet

countworksheet = 1
lastcopy = 2

totalrows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To totalrows + 1
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
            Sheets.Add.Name = countworksheet
            Sht.Range("1:1").Copy Sheets(countworksheet).Cells(1, 1)
            Sht.Range(lastcopy & ":" & i - 1).Copy Sheets(countworksheet).Cells(2, 1)
            lastcopy = i + 1
            countworksheet = countworksheet + 1
            Sht.Activate
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch dude, this was perfect, exactly what I was looking for!